# A new armature is created every time I add a bone

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Every time I try to add another bone in blender 3.4 to the armature it just creates another armature, am I missing something? It's a very frustrating problem and none of the tutorials or posts I have checked seems to reference this.

Comment: If you want to add a new bone in your armature you need to be in Edit mode, is it your problem?

Comment: yes, that was the problem

Comment: I'm sorry, don't mean to be rude... but simply entering "blender rigging tutorial" in the Youtube search brings up a lot of tutorials and I just picked a few randomly, they all showed that you have to go into _Edit Mode_. As I said, no offense here - I just want to highly recommend that you follow tutorials thoroughly and pay attention to details, as it is often not so easy for beginners to find all the tripping hazards in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new bone in your armature you need to be in *Edit* mode (shortcut <kbd>Tab</kbd>):

[image]